# Is there any REST API service available to submit geoJSON file into GeoMesa?

Tags: geojson, geomesa

I have installed GeoMesa version 2.2.0 and have been able to submit (ingest in the GeoMesa terminogy) a geoJSON file into the underlying Accumulo database:

```
geomesa-accumulo ingest -u root -p GisPwd -c geomesa.Links_geom_no /tmp/Links_geom_no.geojson –force
```

The input file *Links_geom_no.geojson* is around 100 MB and the ingestion takes around 5 minutes.

My question is whether there exists an alternative method to submit getJSON data into Accumulo, without requiring access to the console. I have reviewed the [GeoJSON REST API](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/geojson.html#json-attributes) and no relevant functionality seems to exist (e.g. a POST method). The same applies for the [Geoserver Configuration API](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is an add-features POST method in the GeoJSON rest API: https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/2.2.2/user/geojson.html#add-features